# How do I see the files on my Azure server?

Tags: azure, neo4j, server

I have an Azure server, and I've added an instance of Neo4j into it. I want to be able to upload my database backup to my new Neo4j instance, but I don't know how to view my files like through a terminal. There is an ssh instruction that asks me to put `ssh myusername@myip` but this times out.

I'm really struggling to find any helpful articles about how to fix this and would appreciate help.

Comment: This kind of problem involves a lot of troubleshooting and is going to be hard to answer. It sounds like you have an issue with the network security group of your instance, but any number of network problems could also be the culprit. Are you typically able to SSH into instances? Is that what you are asking for help with? What is the issue you want to answer here?

Comment: We used to have an azure server (I didn't set up) that I could ssh into and view the files on my `Terminal`. I've set this one up, but I really don't know what I'm doing (only back-end at the company, and a jr employee to boot!).

I want to be able to upload my Neo4j backup file (`graph.db`) and change the neo4j config settings

Comment: What I'm getting at is that I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to know how to gain SSH access, and then access your files that way? Or how to use non-SSH Azure tools to access your files?

Comment: What azure server? You mean a VM?

Comment: Yeah, my VM. I'd like to be able to access my files like you can with a terminal on Mac

Comment: if you are using Neo4j image from Azure Gallery there an instruction in the description : SSH is available on port 22000 + instance_id. For a 3 instance cluster, SSH ports open would be: 22000, 22001, and 22002. So, maybe you need to use a custom port to connect.

Comment: are you using Neo4j image from Azure Gallery?

Comment: I don't think I am, I haven't come across that in tutorials?